# Converting an sbrz file on a Mac?

Tags: pdf, sbrz

Does anyone know how I can convert/open an `sbrz` file on my Mac? Hoping to turn it into a PDF.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the FileSuffix.com website](http://www.filesuffix.com/en/extension/sbrz), this suffix is for the "Sky Ebook Reader *Encrypted* Ebook". Because the file is encrypted, it is not (generally) legal under DMCA to remove the encryption (in the US). And of course, as you certainly have already found, the [Sky eBook Reader](http://skyebookreader.com/) company only offers their software on Window.

The format is not used by any of the major ebook companies, as far as I've been able to determine. There is a [message on the MobileRead forum](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=228703) from the developer of the Calibre program that he has no plans to support that format. While a solution might be available eventually, it does not appear that one exists at this time.