# How do I read a .sbrz ebook?

Tags: file-format, sbrz

I'm trying to read an eBook that is in `.sbrz` format.  The only way I've found to open `.sbrz` files is a program called *Sky eBook Reader* (apparently the creator of this format), but when I use that, all the pages in the eBook appear blank.  Now it could be that the book is genuinely blank, but the file size is large enough that that's unlikely.

Are there any alternative programs to open `.sbrz` files, or at least to convert it to a more common file format, like PDF or djvu?  The Skybook eReader program doesn't even have print functionality, or else I would simply print as a PDF.

If it helps, I have a computer running Windows XP.

<sub>Note: I was able to get another version of the ebook in `.djvu` format, so I don't really have to worry about `.sbrz` format anymore, but let me leave the question up so that other people who run into this file extension can get help.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I researched this issue in order to answer [this related question](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/607/converting-an-sbrz-file-on-a-mac).

What I found is that there is pretty much no way to read the file short of the software supplied by the [Sky Ebook Reader Company](http://skyebookreader.com/). If you have a legitimate .sbrz file and are unable to read it on your Windows machine with their software, your best bet is to seek support from that company.